# How to insert new row in a dataframe to make it equal row number as the length of given vector in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `mydf` and a vector called `myvec`. The number of rows in dataframe is smaller than the length of the vector. I want to expand the dataframe by inserting the vector element if it is not in the rowname of the dataframe.

```
myvec <- c("apple", "banana", "grapes", "oranges")
```

mydf

```
rowname   codes    remark
apple     44        bad
grapes    54        good
```

result

```
rowname   codes    remark
  apple     44        bad
  banana
  grapes    54        good
  oranges
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the `rowname`s actually rownames? You could do this if you don't subscribe to the [hadley opinion](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/635799723903877125) of `rownames`

```
myvec <- c("apple", "banana", "grapes", "oranges")
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
text = 'rowname   codes    remark
apple     44        bad
grapes    54        good')

rownames(dd) <- dd$rowname
#        rowname codes remark
# apple    apple    44    bad
# grapes  grapes    54   good



`rownames<-`(dd[myvec, ], myvec)

#           rowname codes remark
#   apple     apple    44    bad
#   banana     <NA>    NA   <NA>
#   grapes   grapes    54   good
#   oranges    <NA>    NA   <NA>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert `myvec` into a dataframe and use `merge`:

```
merge(d,data.frame(rowname=myvec),all.y=TRUE)
#   rowname codes remark
# 1   apple    44    bad
# 2  grapes    54   good
# 3  banana    NA   <NA>
# 4 oranges    NA   <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[setDT(list(rowname=myvec)), on='rowname']
#   rowname codes remark
#1:   apple    44    bad
#2:  banana    NA     NA
#3:  grapes    54   good
#4: oranges    NA     NA
```